# How to use Solspace Importer for files

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager, solspace-importer

How can I use Solspace Importer to recognize uploaded files (that are already available in the file manager)?

Possible ways:

- Use the filename?
- Use some file ID?
- Use the files entry name?

I couldn't find anything about in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the data stored in `exp_channel_data` for regular EE **File Upload** fields, you'll see files stored this way, eg: `{filedir_1}myfile.jpg`, where `1` is your upload field ID (this changes depending on your upload directory), and `myfile.jpg` is your filename.

To import **File Upload** field data, you would therefore need the filename, prefixed with `{filedir_X}` (replace `X` with your file upload directory ID) in your source file (eg. your CSV file).